# What is the current draw of an Arduino Due board when sleeping?

Tags: arduino, low-power

I have application which requires 1 year+ operation on a small battery (2xAAA or coin cell). It will be spending 99.99% of the time sleeping only requiring an internal timer for periodic waking and wake on external interrupt. I am considering the 32 bit ARM based Arduino Due board, but nowhere can I find information on how much current the board will consume while the MCU is sleeping.

From experience with other boards, the low power capability of the MCU is negated by power regulators and power LEDs etc.

Comment: USB circuitry also takes up some current.

Comment: For very low power, take a look at the MSP430.

Comment: Ultimately I'll be using an ARM Cortex-M series MCU on a custom board, but I find the Arduino environment great for quick prototyping, so I was hoping to start with the 'Due' and then migrate a custom solution using one of Atmel's or TI's ARM Cortex-M MCUs. But I will need to demonstrate µA sleep mode in operation even in the prototype.

Comment: Then perhaps use the Arduino as a starting point but be prepared to cut a few tracks here and there...

Comment: I can't imagine a Due running on a coin cell battery. Not sure how long it would last on 2 AAA batteries. What specifically is your application?

Comment: @BrianDrummond: That MSP430 dev kit (the Launchpad) is amazing - at $4.30 they're practically giving it away!

Comment: @BrianDrummond A msp430 is not comparable to an ARM setup. That's like comparing a portable cd player to a 10.2 stereo system. Now, the Stellaris Launchpad is comparable. Bit for bit right up there with the Due. And Energia allows you to use Arduino code on the Stellaris Launchpad :D At 13 bucks shipped, it's better. And now I sound like a commercial.

Comment: Application is battery powered ZigBee sensor (probably in conjunction with a XBee). One criteria is GCC tool chain and a bit of future proofing. So ARM Cortex-M seems a good fit. There is GCC toolchain for MSP430 also... so I wouldn't rule it out yet. Stellaris LaunchPad is a strong candidate. If I can get Arduino sketches on the Launchpad with that Energia IDE that would be great. Only downside with LaunchPad is a small modification is needed to achieve true µA operation (a track needs to be cut).

Comment: The NCP1117ST33T3G regulator on the Due will consume some quiescent current unless you cut its traces. That might well be the biggest cost entry in your power budget. The LEDs aren't really a concern unless you turn them on, after all.

Comment: check out energymicro EFM32 AMR Cortex microcontrollers - they are extremely low power and have lots of neat low power tricks

Comment: @Passerby : I agree entirely with your analogy. Now which is a better fit for AAA batteries? :-) More seriously, both MSP430 and Stellaris/Arm have launchpads so it may be possible to test both, or keep the MSP in reserve. Both have gcc (with experimental support for Ada, which I vastly prefer to C).

Comment: @BrianDrummond Both the 430 and Stellaris have Low Power Modes with currents in the microamps (µa). Both have usb and regulator circuitry, but can be powered directly cutting out draw on those chips. The msp is easier to make a simple board out of (Chip + 2 resistors and cap), while the stellaris launchpad would be dedicated. The msp is a 16bit while the Stel is a Arm workhorse. The Stel has 5v tolerant pins, the 430 doesn't. As for a year on 2 AAAs for 1 year, not sure depending on you often it wakes, what it does with the xigbee. If its near sunlight, you could throw in solar panel.

Comment: @BrianDrummond with rechargeable batteries. It's more than plausible that you can get a year that way.

Answer (score 6):

While the processor itself supports very low-power modes the [LM2734 Datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2734.pdf) shows a typical quiescent current of 1.5mA. It is also only a step-down regulator so the Arduino Due shows a minimum operating voltage of 6V, but you'd really want to aim higher say by using 6 cells for 9V so it continues operating once the batteries are getting low.

If you used 6 x 1.5 AAA after a quick search the highest capacity I could spot was 1200mA/hr so that would give around 1200 / 1.5 = 800 hours or about a month of operation.

But that's only taking the main regulator into account, there's also op-amps and a secondary linear regulator along with a few resistor dividers. I do not know the exact answer but as a guestimate would say it's likely to be more in the order of 5mA (10 days of operation) and not really suitable for your intended purpose.